# cell in Excel "Number stored as text"

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# program that takes a text file of a legacy report and maps to an excel sheet.
but for the transaction cells it is output as "Number stored as text" this does not allow 
any formatting. We want to show 1,000.00 but it only as 1000.

Is there a way I can get this formatting? those columns are Balance and Amount.
here it is defined:

```
ndcRange = currentSheet.Cells[transactionRowNo + pageOffset, 13];
ndcRange.NumberFormat = "@";
ndcRange.Value2 = tr.Amount;

ndcRange = currentSheet.Cells[transactionRowNo + pageOffset, 16];
ndcRange.NumberFormat = "@";
ndcRange.Value2 = tr.Balance;
```

Here is some code where some formatting is done:

```
string balance = transaction;

if (lastSpaceIndex != -1)
{

   balance = transaction.Substring(lastSpaceIndex, (transaction.Length)lastSpaceIndex);

}

transac.Balance = balance;
transaction = transaction.Replace(balance, "");


transaction = transaction.Trim();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(transaction))
{
    transac.Description = transaction;
}
patient.TransactionsList.Add(transac);
```

Comment: How are you creating and/or populating the workbook/worksheet in C#? There are a great many ways to do this, so the answer depends on what you are doing.

Comment: How are you setting the cell value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Range.NumberFormat from the Microsoft Excel Object Library. Check this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084).

Sample code:

```
oRng = oSheet.get_Range("C2", "C1000"); //change this range to suit your scenario
oRng.Formula = "<any formula you may be using already or skip it>";
oRng.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00";
```

**References:**

[How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084)

[StackOverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828600/convert-excel-cell-value-from-text-to-number-using-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't think Range.NumberFormat will work, since the numbers are stored as text.

Comment: The numbers are stored as text because of his code using .NumberFormat. He just needs to use the right format instead of using "@" as suggested in the sample code.

Comment: Yes, you're right of course.  I had missed the fact that he was using "@".

Comment: You didn't miss it :) The OP was edited to include the code AFTER you put in your comment. Happens all the time.

Answer (score 3):

I think the trick here is to get the number into the cell as a number rather than as text.  If `tr.Balance` is a string, you can convert it to a double using TryParse:

```
object StringToDoubleIfPossible(string s)
{
    double parseResult;
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && double.TryParse(s, out parseResult) ? (object)parseResult : s;
}
```

EDIT: The string.IsNullOrEmpty() call is not necessary.  I put it in because I wasn't sure whether TryParse could handle a null string.  It can.  This is better:

```
object StringToDoubleIfPossible(string s)
{
    double parseResult;
    return double.TryParse(s, out parseResult) ? (object)parseResult : s;
}
```

EDIT:

Duh!  barrowc is correct.  I was wondering why the number was going in as text in the first place.  I should have paid more attention to that '@' format.

Answer (score 2):

Your code `ndcRange.NumberFormat = "@"` is what is setting the number format to Text in the first place. Just change the `@` to an appropriate number format instead (e.g. the one suggested in Kash's answer) before you insert the data